# can I deduce some C++ arguments when translating method by SWIG?

Tags: swig

(I am rewording the question to use an example, so it is perhaps more clear what I want. )

Say I have a C++ function:

```
void foobar(int arg0, int arg1);
```

which I want translated into Python by SWIG.  However, in Python, I only want to use argument `arg1`, and compute `arg0` to be the same.  In other words, I want to make it so that Python

```
>>>foobar(x)
```

be equivalent to C++

```
foobar(x, x);
```

for any integer x.   How?

Alex's answer is pointing in some direction, but does not quite go far enough.  Specifically

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) int arg0 {
}
```

is very helpful in that it allows me to pass 1 argument, and Python does not complain.  Good.  But, the remaining part is, how to compute `arg0` from `arg1` in a typemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [multi-argument typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_multi_argument_typemaps_patterns).  Note the typemap will match any function that has the set of parameters in its parameter list.  this is most often used to map a Python string to a pair of parameters in C such as a `char*, size_t`, but can be used whenever a single Python parameter can be mapped to multiple arguments:

```
%module x

// for a single input parameter in Python, if a function takes two integers
// named explicitly "int arg0, int arg1", map the two parameters to that
// same input.
%typemap(in) (int arg0, int arg1) %{
    $1 = PyInt_AsLong($input);
    $2 = $1;
%}

%inline %{
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int arg0, int arg1)
{
    printf("%d %d\n",arg0,arg1);
}
void bar(int arg0, int arg1, int other)
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n",arg0,arg1,other);
}
void baz(int other, int arg0, int arg1)
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n",other,arg0,arg1);
}
%}
```

Output:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.foo(5)
5 5
>>> x.bar(1,5)
1 1 5
>>> x.baz(5,1)
5 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` and `argout` typemap types. Their main purpose is to allow to return multiple values in additional arguments. But the side effect is you hide those arguments in the target language:

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0, noblock=1) type1 *arg1 {
  type1 arg1;
  $1 = &arg1;
}

%typemap(argout) type1 *arg1 {
  // now *$1 has the value of Py_calculate_value_of_arg1()
  // you can do additional checks here
}

returnType foobar(type0 arg0, type1 *arg1) {
    *arg1 = Py_calculate_value_of_arg1();
}
```

The python code will be

```
foobar(arg0_value)
```

See the docs http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn61

Comment: yes I was just trying your first answer, did not work, let me try after your edit, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I missed `typemap(in)`. For the reference you see https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/sphinxbase/swig/typemaps.i I used the trick above to turn C-style error codes into exceptions.